# DAVID enrichment analysis using R version 4.1.2

Tags: r, bioinformatics, rna-seq

I need to run DAVID enrichment analysis on list of genes I got after differential expression analysis and I found that the package 'RDavidWebService' is not available any more for the new releases of R and bioconductor.

Is someone know about an alternative way to run DAVID analysis on list of genes ?
[I also found the clusterProfiler package but its DAVID function uses RDavidWebService so I cant use it).

Thanks a lot :)

run DAVID enrichment analysis with the new version of R

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to it? I am trying to run `enrichDAVID` from `clusterProfiler`, but it asks for `RDavidWebService` package that I am unable to install.